# How Divide and Conquer algorithms work with a given input?

Tags: recursion, input, divide

I've written a divide and conquer algorithm in java.
The problem is, I've tested it an it works, except I'm not really sure why or what it does with the data. I know the it splits the array into sub parts, but apart from that i'm confused what happens what they're returning everything.
For example, does the smallest base case return its number and compare that? Also what order does the recursive take place if theres more than one recursion call in a function?
My code is:

```
public static int FindMin(int[] array, int low, int high)
{
int min = 0, min1 = 0, min2 = 0;
int mid = 0;
if (low == high)
    {
    min = array[low];
    }
else if (low == (high - 1))
    {
    if (array[low] < array[high])
        {
        min = array[low];
        }
    else if (array[low] > array[high]);
        {
        min = array[high];
        }
    }
else
    {
    mid = (low + high)/2;
    min1 = FindMin(array, low, mid);
    min2 = FindMin(array, mid+1, high);
    if (min1 < min2)
        {
        min = min1;
        }
    else
        {
        min = min2;
        }
    }
return min;
}
```

Basically what I want to know is:
how the algorithm would work if it was given the input: 3,6,1,5,7,2,1.
Like what it returns and things like that.

I'm sorry if the question is somewhat ambiguous but I know how to code it, I just cant seem to understand how it returns everything, regardless of all the google pages and pdfs i've started at.

Thanks for all the help anyway! :D

Comment: the debugger is your friend

Comment: I would say it's like Mergesort. I will loop deeper.

Comment: Tried a debugger tool, but it didn't really help, still about as confused as I was before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so now I got a grasp what it does and how it works.

It's quite simple. For a given array, you divide it into two parts further and further. Now every recursive code has to stop at some point, yours stop in two situation.

```
A) When the part this recursive needs to process is sized one.
B) When the part this recursive needs to process is sized two.
```

So when condition A is met, your function simply returns low, which is equal to high.

When condition B is met, your function compares `array[low]` and `array[high]`, and returns the index of the value which is lower.

If the recursive function has to process a range of more than 2, it divides into two part, and hand those two part to two more recursive parts.

For example, for a given array like this.

```
array[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}

You will first split it to two parts of {1, 2} [0...1] and {3, 4, 5} [2...4].

    And now since the first part is of size 2, the index 0 gets returned because 1 is smaller than 2, obviously.

    And then the other part {3, 4, 5} gets divided again, to two parts, {3} [2...2], and {4, 5} [3...4].

        The first subpart of sized one, gets returned immediately, because it's of size one, return value = 2.

        And then the second part which is sized two, get compared and returned, return value = 3.

    Now these two return values (2 and 3) gets processed, comparing array[2] and array[3], array[2] is definitely smaller, so it returns 2.

Now those two return values (0 and 2) gets processed, comparing the two, we can see the minima is at index 0, of value 1.
```

There's a flaw in your code, at the last part, you should compare `array[min1]` and `array[min2]` and return `min1` or `min2`.

It's quite a mess, hope you can understand. Another things is my syntax, {`data`}[`index range`]

Comment: I agree with your analysis of the algorithm but I differ on the diagnosis of the bugs. `min1` and `min2` are not indices in the array, they are minimum values of the two sub-arrays, so that part of the OP's code was correct, though other parts were not.

Comment: Thanks for that, Nice, clear and easy to understand, especially with the explanation part of it, I had a fair idea of the exit sequences but it was nice to know when and how they were tripped through the code. Thanks! :D EDIT I was also just thinking about it then and you really did clear my understandings, I was thinking about it like a tree with two branching paths, each set of children compares their values and gives the minimum to the parent similar to a has table or other tree symbolised algorithms!

Comment: @Simon Thanks for the correction, you are correct about that. I overlooked that part of the code.

Comment: @CailDemetri As Simon stated, you are returning value of the smallest part, not the index. But still the algorithm is correct. I will however suggest you to go with an index-based return value since it will deliver better performance in situations where the data type to compare is complex or very large, index, as integers will be much smaller.

Comment: @CailDemetri Also, I will suggest you take a look at something called RMQ, or Range Minimum Query. Given an array of data and a range, and find the minima in that range. From your algorithm, you have to do that calculation each time in approximately O(nlogn), with RMQ, you can do that in O(1) with O(n) preprocessing. RMQ is designed to take multiple queries, but might come in handy someday. I personally had ask a few questions in that area.

Answer (score 1):

While a debugger is useful, sometimes the right sort of logfile output can provide more insight. I added a call to the following function at the end of your `FindMin()` function, just before the `return min;` statement:

```
public static void pr (int[] array, int low, int high, int min) {
    System.out.print("low = ");
    System.out.print(low);
    System.out.print(", high = ");
    System.out.print(high);
    System.out.print(", array = ");
    for (int i = low; i <= high; i++) {
        System.out.print(array[i]);
        if (i < high) {
            System.out.print(",");
        }
    }
    System.out.print(" min = ");
    System.out.print(min);
    System.out.print("\n");
}
```

The output I get is:

```
low = 0, high = 1, array = 3,6 min = 6
low = 2, high = 3, array = 1,5 min = 5
low = 0, high = 3, array = 3,6,1,5 min = 5
low = 4, high = 5, array = 7,2 min = 2
low = 6, high = 6, array = 1 min = 1
low = 4, high = 6, array = 7,2,1 min = 1
low = 0, high = 6, array = 3,6,1,5,7,2,1 min = 1
```

This tells me that, although `FindMin()` is returning the correct answer for this test case, it is doing so somewhat by accident. I'm looking now to see why ...

(EDIT)

One issue is that the code:

```
if (array[low] < array[high])
{
    min = array[low];
}
else if (array[low] > array[high]);  // <- stray semi-colon here
{
    min = array[high];
}
```

... does not consider the case where `array[low] == array[high]`. Either the first comparison should be `<=` or the second should be `>=`, otherwise there will be cases where the returned value of `min` will be its initialised value of 0 because neither of the branches of the `if` will apply.

(FURTHER EDIT)

You have a stray semi-colon that is causing your bug. The semi-colon after the test that I've marked above terminates the statement. That prematurely terminated `else if` is then followed by another statement that always sets `min` to equal `array[high]` regardless of the preceding tests.

Changing this code to:

```
if (array[low] < array[high])
    {
    min = array[low];
    }
else 
    {
    min = array[high];
    }
```

... gives the following output:

```
low = 0, high = 1, array = 3,6 min = 3
low = 2, high = 3, array = 1,5 min = 1
low = 0, high = 3, array = 3,6,1,5 min = 1
low = 4, high = 5, array = 7,2 min = 2
low = 6, high = 6, array = 1 min = 1
low = 4, high = 6, array = 7,2,1 min = 1
low = 0, high = 6, array = 3,6,1,5,7,2,1 min = 1
```

... which you can see is producing the correct result from each recursive call.

Comment: Wow, thanks for all the effort! I've gone through your answer, the one above and a basic recursion video and i'm starting to get the hang of things now. I thought there may have been something wrong with my algorithms due to it returning the wrong answers if the min was at array[2] or array[0] so thats for clearing that part up as well, much appreciated!

Comment: Glad to help. When I started programming, I thought it was all about inspiration. Now, after many years, I've learned that a methodical approach is by far the most important contribution I make to a development team. Write a little code, test it a lot till I'm sure it is right, write a little more, test it more, etc. means I deliver more good output more quickly and I help my colleagues do the same. If this answer meets your needs, please check the box to accept it.